# Disabling access to a form when a new form is opened from C# class library

Tags: c#, winforms, showdialog

I have two windows forms `Form1` and `Form2` and a c# class library `CLProduct`.

Now, `Form1` is already open and a method in `CLProduct` class is called which shows `Form2` and at this point I would like to restrict access to `Form1` until `Form2` is closed.

I have the below code in my method in CLProduct which load

```
var _frm2= new Form2();
_frm2.ShowDialog();
```

I know that `ShowDialog` loads a modal which by default restricts the access to Form1 when `ShowDialog` is called from Form1 but in my scenario `ShowDialog` is actually called from a Class which for obvious reasons doesn't restrict `Form1` as it is not called from `Form1`

Form2 is running on a worker thread that's created in Form1 as follows

```
                if (pPBackgroundWorker.IsBusy == false)
                {                   
                    // Start the asynchronous operation.
                    pPBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
                }
```

Is there a way to handle this from `Form1_Load()`?

Comment: Are you the author of `CLProduct`? I might be mistaken but I think there is an option to pass a `Form` to another `Form` so that one considers the other its parents and the behavior you desire can be achieved. But you would need to modify how `Form2` in you example above is created. // Look at `ShowDialog(this)` where `this` is a reference to you "current" UI.

Comment: If you are not the author of `CLProduct` you might have to make a little "trick" so to say. Create another `Form` in `Form1` that does nothing, display it with `ShowDialog` so that is blocks `Form1` at the same time show `Form2` as you do currently. If you can determine when `Form2` has closed you can close the new `Form` and then allow user access to `Form1` again.

Comment: In general, ShowDialog() does not have much trouble finding an owner window for the dialog if you don't use the ShowDialog(owner) overload.  Although it is easy enough to come up with one, Application.OpenForms[0] is usually good.  Crystal ball says that the code runs on a worker thread.  That's a pretty serious problem that you need to fix, the side-effects can be *very* unpleasant.  Use the debugger's Debug > Windows > Threads window to verify.

Comment: @KDecker Yes, I am the author of `CLProduct` but as `ShowDialog` is on a class which doesn't have a UI

Comment: @HansPassant Can you please elaborate on this

Comment: No, we need to stop guessing at this and that can only happen when you *first* use the debugger and the ShowDialog(owner) overload.

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry I am confused, when you say owner, is this Form2?

Comment: That is the dialog.  The owner window is the one it is on top of, ought to be an instance of Form1 if your description is accurate.

Comment: @HansPassant Form2 is the window which is on top of Form1 as per the description and I am already invoking form2 with `_frm2.ShowDialog()` where _frm2 is an instance of Form2

Comment: @KDecker Can you give an overview of implemenation of what you said?

Comment: You need to pass the form1 object in the call to ShowDialog to declare that form1 is the parent of form2. Use: **_frm2.ShowDialog(_frm1)**

Comment: @HansPassant. Yes It is running on a worker thread which is why `Form2` doesn't find its appropriate user

Comment: If you have no control over the thread at all, so you can properly use the BackgroundWorker or Task class, then you'll have to help.  Create an instance of the `Progress<T>` class in your constructor.  Use its Report() method to activate the code that displays the form.  But first look how that thread got created, the Call Stack window should give some insight.

Comment: @HansPassant : thread was created on a button click in Form1. I have updated the question

Comment: @BharatGupta I tried implementing it but it behaves behaves the same way

Answer (score 0):

You should simply be able to call `ShowDialog` for `From2` and pass `Form1` as an argument and get the desired behavior. (`_frm2.ShowDialog(_frm1)`)

But as HansPassant points out in the comments, if `Form2` does not find the appropriate owner itself it most likely means that it is running on a worker thread which can result in some pretty nasty bugs/issues.

Comment: Yes, It is running on a worker thread.So, May be it is not good to follow this implementation.  Is there a better solution to it?

Comment: That question is much deeper than I could answer in a comment. Its about how the `CLProduct` library works internally. Knowing nothing about what it does or how it works currently, and not really having time to study it, means that I probably cannot help you with that. // Its about how WinForms works interanlly to handle and coordinate the applications forms. @HansPassant would have a much more elegant way to put that.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have a worker thread which is invoked on a button click from form1 and that particular thread invoked a method which invokes the form2